# Interfacing USB with a microcontroller

Tags: usb, stm32, stm32f10x

I am designing a development board for STM32F103 microcontroller. I plan to implement an on-board USB for interfacing with the uC. I referred a few designs online and have always found some pull up logic on the D+ line.

Can someone please explain me the use of the pull-up logic and also tell me whether the 22R resistors are necessary or not.

This is the image I am using as a reference.
[image: STM32 USB Circuit]

Comment: You need pull-up to tell computer that device is connected. When you reboot your MCU, pullup from D+ removes & computer will reconnect on its appearance.

Comment: Lose the pull-up circuitry. The USB peripheral should be handling that unless specifically stated. Lose the 47pF caps. Keep the 22 Ohm resistors. Add a dual pack sterring diode+TVS combo that was designed for USB.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> A USB device must indicate its speed by pulling either the D+ or D-
>   line high to 3.3 volts. A full speed device, pictured below will use a
>   pull up resistor attached to D+ to specify itself as a full speed
>   device. These pull up resistors at the device end will also be used by
>   the host or hub to detect the presence of a device connected to its
>   port. Without a pull up resistor, USB assumes there is nothing
>   connected to the bus. Some devices have this resistor built into its
>   silicon, which can be turned on and off under firmware control, others
>   require an external resistor.

http://www.beyondlogic.org/usbnutshell/usb2.shtml

The series resistance are for line termination

> The Universal Serial Bus (USB) line termintation is specified in the
>   USB 1.1 specification to insure proper terminations so that signal
>   integrity is maintained. The termination requirement varies depending
>   on what driver chipset is used, whether the port is upstream or
>   downstream, and if the transceiver operates in full or low speed.
>
> When the USB 1.1 specification was written, a series resistor between
>   the range of 28Ω to 44Ω was required. Most USB drivers will require a
>   termination resistor of 16 - 33Ω.

http://www.semtech.com/images/datasheet/usb%20line%20termination%20_ag.pdf